# Displaying two widgets in MainWindow

Tags: qt

I am new to Qt. As it stands, I have a table with a button `btn`. When the button is clicked the `setCentralWidget(view)` takes over the window so I can no longer see the table obviously. But if I remove the `setCentralWidget(view)`, nothing displays when I click the button.

Is there a way I can display both in the same window? Split or dock maybe?

(I have removed code that is irrelevant to my question)

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    //etc

    packet = new QTabWidget;
    setCentralWidget(packet)
}

//other code

void MainWindow::create(const QString &a)
{
      QTableWidget* table = new QTableWidget;
      int tabIndex = packet->addTab(table, a);
      packet->setCurrentIndex(tabIndex);

      table->setRowCount(1);
      table->setColumnCount(2);

      table->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString("a;Simulator").split(";"));"));

      table->setItem(0,0,new QTableWidgetItem(a));

      QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("load", this);
      connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(sim()));
      table->setCellWidget(0,1, btn);
}

void MainWindow::sim()
{
    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(QRect(-10, -10, 100, 50));
    QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView();
    scene->addText("Network");
    view->setScene(scene);
    view->setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 100, 50));

    setCentralWidget(view);
}
```

Comment: Style nitpick: Avoid the split(). `table->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList() << "a" << "Simulator")`

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [QMdiArea](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmdiarea.html) class - it's designed to be used as the central widget of a Main Window that can have many inner widgets.  It has a variety of layout styles as well - scroll down on that page to see the examples.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass QWidget. For example make your own MyWidget class. And this class will include a QGraphicsView and a QTabWidget in a splitter for example. And in your MainWindow set the central widget as an instance of MyWidget.